# Анимация передачи данных WPF

Tags: wpf

К примеру есть 2 объекта. Нужно каким - либо способом визуализировать передачу данных из объекта 'А' до объекта 'Б', скажем в виде анимационной полосы. Есть ли какие либо встроенные методы или сторонние библиотеки, которые позволяют это написать грубо говоря в одну строку?

Comment: можно progressbar заполнять пока не закончена передча вот так  не плохо бы знать время передачи или сколько данных передано и знать сколько всего передается и  на основе этого заполнять его

Comment: Я сделал спинер. Включал анимацию перед началом передачи и выключал анимацию после того как передача закончена.Вот только передачу лучше делать чрез Task иначе анимация подвиснет и не будет крутится спинер